# Zecher L'Churban - Why a plate at Tenayim and a glass at the Chupah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, wedding, churban-destruction, zekher-lchurban

When a person gets engaged and married there are various things that we do as a Zecher L'Churban. At the Tenayim (whether done immediately or at the wedding) we break an earthernware plate, at the Chupah we break a glass. Why do we Davka break an earthernware plate at the Tenayim and a glass at the Chupah?

Comment: Just before the chupah, the chasan has some ashes on his forehead to remember the Bais Hamikdash.

Comment: I learned this week, that only Ashkenazim do the ash on the head.

Comment: @avi That's odd considering it's an explicit gemara ([BB60b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=60b&format=pdf)) quoted by all the major rishonim, shulchan aruch etc.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18255/5323

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I heard it is because one can "fix" a wedding through a divorce (like a glass that can be melted back together). There is no way out of a tnaim, however, so it is like an earthenware plate that can't be fixed.

Comment: The Toldos Aharon writes this in the name of the Ba'al Shem Tov. See footnote to #970 in Taamei Minhagim: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=424

Comment: Can't you also get out of a tnaim with kiddushin then get?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's not getting out of a Tnayim. One fulfills the Tenaim through marriage and then leave the marriage through a Get

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What's the difference? In both cases it's no longer binding on you.

Comment: @DoubleAA If a person vows to get married to someone and divorces her, did he fulfill his Shevua?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: @DoubleAA and would likewise fulfill his Tenayim

Comment: I don't see where you are going with this