# Source listing all Jewish wedding customs?

Tags: minhag, wedding

Is there a comprehensive source that lists all various orthodox wedding customs (mitzvah tantz, mezinkah, etc.)?

Comment: "[A] comprehensive source that lists all various orthodox wedding customs" may not exist, but [_Made in Heaven: A Jewish Wedding Guide_ by R' Aryeh Kaplan](http://www.amazon.com/Made-Heaven-Jewish-Wedding-Guide/dp/0940118114) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: White wine at the chuppah.

Comment: Are you looking for customs at all Orthodox weddings or all customs for Orthodox weddings in different communities?

Comment: BTW "mezinkah" is not a Jewish wedding custom.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm pretty sure it has become one. At least for a substantial number.

Comment: @SAH It's not a Jewish custom even if lots of Jews do it. It's not a Jewish custom to wear shoes or to root for the Yankees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HaNissuim KHilkhatam is a good source of varied minhagim.

I would also look at Rav Daniel Sperber's Minhagei Yisrael which is an 8 volume set documenting thousands and thousands of minhagim from around the Jewish world.

Answer (score 7):

[Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Nesuin 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/46545) & [Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Nesuin 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/46546)

Comment: +1, a great source, though I doubt it's what the asker sought (emphasis supplied): "a **comprehensive** source that lists **all** various orthodox wedding customs". That probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @msh210 I was actually hoping for a website or some other digital format which many people could add to. Something like that could conceivably list them all, no?

Comment: @PM: Conceivably? Yes. Likely? Not IMO. Customs could vary from town to town within a single area of the Ukraine (for example).