# Does the timing of breaking a dish after the reading of the te'na'im before a wedding matter?

Tags: minhag, wedding

At a recent wedding I attended, the mothers of the bride accidentally [broke the dish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18250/sources-for-about-breaking-a-plate-at-a-wedding) after the signing of the *te'na'im* but before it was read out publicly. It seems like the regular procedure is to break the dish after the reading of the *te'na'im* so there was a tumult and a new dish was brought to break again after the *te'na'im* were read.

Is there really a difference if it is broken before the signing of the *te'na'im*, after the signing or after the reading of the *te'na'im*? If so does it have anything to do with the [reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18250/sources-for-about-breaking-a-plate-at-a-wedding) for this practice?

Comment: I edited out the duplicate portion and added an explicit link to the other question. I also altered the title to match the question.

Comment: the breaking is not a Kinyan,  so what are you asking,  it is not clear for me.